# Can a Tsunami early warning turn "on" remotely some cell phones in Japan?

Tags: mobile, government

In Japan, some [televisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthquake_Early_Warning_(Japan)#Television) and radios seem to be capable of getting out of sleep mode if a tsunami warning is issued.

> If tsunami warnings are issued, the Emergency Warning Broadcast system
>   utilizes 1seg to automatically turn on (and tune to NHK) all radios
>   and televisions with 1seg technology in the areas at risk. All
>   warnings are broadcast in five languages: English, Mandarin, Korean
>   and Portuguese, as well as Japanese.[17]

Here is the definition of [sleep mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_mode) from wikipedia

> **Sleep mode** is a low power mode for electronic devices such as
>   computers, televisions, and remote controlled devices. These modes
>   save significantly on electrical consumption compared to leaving a
>   device fully on and, upon resume, allow the user to avoid having to
>   reissue instructions or to wait for a machine to reboot. **Many devices
>   signify this power mode with a pulsed or red colored LED power light.**

However, I would like to know if similar technology has been deployed in Japan for some cell phones. I heard rumors that this was the case also, but the wikipedia article seems [unclear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthquake_Early_Warning_(Japan)#Mobile_phone_networks) about this (and unfortunately, several of the references listed at the end of the wikipedia article are in Japanese).

Just to be clear. I'm not looking for a sleep mode on a cell phone. I realize that if the led light on a cell phone is on, it can still receive messages and commands. I'm especially looking to know if a Tsunami warning can turn on some Japanese phones that were previously turned "off" with the power button.

Please note that I do not care to know if it is [possible](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12740/can-a-powered-down-cell-phone-be-turned-on-remotely). Nor do I care if the NSA [can do it](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/59112/47326). I am only looking for evidence, either first-hand accounts or a written source, that this kind of turning-on technology has been at least partially implemented in Japan for tsunami early warnings on some cell phones at least.

Lacking this evidence, I'll settle for anyone who went through a tsunami warning in Japan these past couple of years (without hearing about cell phones turning themselves on. If this had been really the case, I would assume that Japanese people would have talked about it amongst themselves).