# Does the Dreamy Smurf tool really exist?

Tags: phone, smartphone

Dreamy Smurf is a program that allows its user to activate a target's phone when it is apparently turned off. Is it real or not, and how can this work?

Comment: also see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/59093/snowden-the-nsa-can-remotely-turn-on-your-iphone?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Where did you smurf this idea?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to turn on a device that is COMPLETELY powered down, however I have heard of some bugs that can prevent the device from completely powering down; thus making it possible to wake them from the fake "shutdown."

Sources: Personal experience and [Link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12740/can-a-powered-down-cell-phone-be-turned-on-remotely)